# Protractor: How to handle blur event in input textbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am testing an app where we have written a directive which will attach blur event to input element,
Once user type some value and come out from textbox then it will check if value is not duplicate,
based on response it will set value using ctrl.$setValidity('unique', true);

When I am setting some unique to textbox using elem.sendKeys('newVal') and go to another input, it does not trigger blur event attached to the element.

Comment: Maybe you could try [Protractor's click function](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click)?

Comment: Share your code and html code.

Comment: tried, it didn't work

Comment: Sample code can be found here
Note: This is not working code, just to show how code is written
https://plnkr.co/edit/JjUpk6DByTnm9eeWWKQI?p=catalogue

Comment: Are you following this?
`http://moduscreate.com/protractor-and-page-objects/`
`http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects`

Comment: I am using astrolabe for pageObjects
https://www.npmjs.com/package/astrolabe